# Connecting Nginx Server to OpenVPN and Accessing it from the Internet

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, openvpn

I have an Nginx server running on my local network, and I want to make it accessible from the internet via an OpenVPN connection. Here are the details of my setup:

- Ubuntu Server Local IP Address: `192.168.29.110`
- OpenVPN Access Server IP Address: `139.59.60.64`

**Notes**:

1. OpenVPN Access Server is running on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu Server (called *OpenVPN-server* hereon)
2. Nginx is running on a local Ubuntu Server at home (called *Nginx-server* hereon)
3. Home network (ISP) doesn't allow dedicated IP / port forwarding due to which I'm unable to access my *Nginx-server* from outside the LAN network. Therefore the goal is to connect local *Nginx-server* to *OpenVPN-server* so as to use the IP address of the VPN connected and thereby allow *Nginx-server* to be accessible from the word wide web (public internet).
4. UFW is disabled on both *OpenVPN-server* as well as *Nginx-server*.
5. DigitalOcean firewall is disabled.

**Network Configuration on Nginx-server**:
Netplan configuration (/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml):

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.29.110/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.29.1
  version: 2
```

**Nginx Configuration on Nginx-server**:
Nginx configuration file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 139.59.60.64;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.29.110;  # Update this line
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

**Challenges and Questions**:

1. Replacing OpenVPN Dashboard with Nginx Landing Page:

- I currently access the OpenVPN Access Server dashboard from the IP
  address `139.59.60.64`. After establishing a connection from
  *Nginx-server* to the *OpenVPN-server*, I want to replace the dashboard
  with my local Nginx landing page. How can I achieve this?

2. Making Nginx Accessible from the Internet via OpenVPN:

- After connecting to the *OpenVPN-server*, what changes do I need to make in my Nginx configuration file and Netplan configuration on Nginx-server to access my *Nginx-server* from the internet?